# RFT build proxy on custom GUI (SWT) component

Tags: rft

I have an `SWT` project, where are several custom GUI elements, and i try to find a way, to build some kind of proxy on top of them, like the default ones built on top of `Labels`, `Texts`, etc. Is there a way to do this? It would be really convenient, to create a custom `GuiTestObject` subclass, and use it (make RFT use it?) to identify these custom GUI elements, like [`KTable`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ktable/) for example, because now these controls are handled by the best class known by RFT, like `Composite` or `ScrolledComposite`, so it's impossible to expose the custom properties of these classes for testing, and the best way to test these elements is by image comparison.

If this is not possible, then is there a way, to somehow get a reference to the actual ui component from a `GuiTestObject`? I tried in debug mode, but it looks like, that the reference is intentionally hidden somehow. Is there a way, to bypass this, and somehow access the reference? (I couldn't see the actual ui element neither using the debugger, nor using reflection).

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The TestObject that you have available in the script should represent the actual object in the  AUT.
As you said the methods exposed to the script  would be limited to what is provided by the TestObject however RFT has API called  "invoke"  that you can use to invoke some method directly on the  control.
You should find more info on invoke here: [Using Invoke in RFT](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/qualitymanagement/entry/february_28_2012_1_34_am34?lang=en)

Second , you should be able to extend an Existing proxy  using the Proxy SDK of RFT  where you can add custom behavior for the proxies

You can get more info aobut proxy SDK here:
[Proxy SDK in RFT](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/rfthelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.test.ft.proxysdk.doc/topics/c_pr_proxy_sdk.html)